# After creating new entity in Jhipster, its not creating table in existing database

Tags: java, database, entity, jhipster

I have two entities in jhipster application and respective two tables in database. Now I have added new entity in jhipster using jhipster entity command but after running application its not creating new entity table in database. I have tried everything but nothing works hence I have deleted existing database(took backup) and created new one then after running application Its works.

So Can anyone give me solution for this weird problem. Pls find below entity.json file

```html
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "clientRootFolder": "",
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipName": "userId",
            "otherEntityName": "user",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "login",
            "ownerSide": true,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "emailStats"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "unDeliverable",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "autoReply",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "deliveryFailed",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "normal",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "mailReceivedDate",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20181030122031",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "entityTableName": "email_stats",
    "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
    "pagination": "pagination"
}
```

Comment: please post your JHipster configuration, .json file .

Comment: @NgSharma - added. Pls check

Comment: Try this  command jhipster --force --with-entities ?

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, the tables are created. However, there must be some error in the liquibase configuration.

Try generating the entity by creating a jh file and importing the same.

Please refer: https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/

Answer (score 1):

Can you find the new changeSet xml file under 'src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog'?
If yes, just check if it's also in master.xml

When deleted the existing database, I usually use this command './mvnw liquibase:dropAll' and './mvnw clean'.

Hope you fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just try this simple workaround.

Rename your database to something else, then create a new database with a name same as you provide in your application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml , then ./mvnw

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `./mvnw clean` or `./gradlew clean` will fix the problem in the `dev` environment, then run `./mvnw` again.

Answer (score -1):

- Find `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20211215051157_added_entity_NewEntity.xml` file in project.
- Copy File name
- Open `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml`.
- Make manual entry for added new entity as follows(if no entry is there)

```
<include file="config/liquibase/changelog/20211215051157_added_entity_NewEntity.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

- Run application.
  This has solved my problem of not creating corresponding table for newly created entity.